# VS debugger not showing some variables

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017

I'm using VS2017, attaching to a running process (a Windows service) and breaking on a breakpoint.
When I do that, some variables that should be in scope are not recognized by the debugger - not shown in the Locals or Autos windows, no tooltip in the editor, can't add a watch or evaluate them in the Immediate window. In these cases, I'm getting an error "*CS0103: The name '...' does not exist in the current context*"

[image: sample]

The executable and the referenced project where the breakpoint is placed are both built in the Debug configuration, optimization switched off. I've tried rebuilding the solution so that there's no old .pdb or such, with no effect.

Any tips what might cause this? How to make the debugger show all variables?

Comment: Please also add the stack trace that VS shows to your question

Comment: @voidengine, If you enable the "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" under Tools->Options->Debugging->General, how about the result? If still no help, please provide us a sample of code you have the trouble with.

Comment: @TarunLalwani There's no stack trace, the code works. But when I try to evaluate some variable like 'flow' in the Immediate window, I'm only getting "The name 'flow' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT No change when I enable that option. I'll try to replicate this issue on some minimal sample which I can share, but not sure if I'll manage that. Still open to another tips on what might help.

Comment: @voidengine, Whether there are two or more project in the same solution? If you select one project in solution explorer before you type the command line in Immediate Window, how about the result? I also met this error messages before which was related to the assembly references. You also would check that whether the specific code was really called/used in your side.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT Just selecting the project in the Solution explorer seems to do the trick. Why?! If you make this into an answer, I'll accept it. An explanation would be appretiated

Comment: @voidengine,Glad to know that it works well. Maybe the specific assembly was referenced in one project, and the debug window doesn't know that which variable is the specific one or others. Anyway, glad to know that it works well now. I just add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

Please selected one of your projects in Solution Explorer before you type the command line in Immediate Window. It will work well.

Comment: Helps at least some of the times. Explanation how or why this works would be appretiated

Comment: I don't get the answer, could someone explain it a bit more elaborately? I am facing the same issue.